# Long label breaks the design

Tags: html, forms, input, label, responsive

[Image for ref.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd4eJ.jpg)

In form a few fields have long labels due to which my design breaks.

**Need help implementing these goals**

- Label should come in one line, or if it's coming in two, then the  other fields should match.
- I don't want a label look like "sample label for re...."

HTML Code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Office/Business Address1:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Office/Business Address2:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Nearest Police Station(Permanent):</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Permanent Address District:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML code of your label to see the structure?

Comment: You could add a css code `white-space: nowrap` on the label class

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: You would probably need to use something like css grid for this if you want to keep your inputs aligned when labels run over multiple lines

Comment: <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <label>Office/Business Address1:</label>
   <input class="form-control"  type="text" value="">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <label>Office/Business Address2:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
 </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  <label>Nearest Police Station(Permanent):</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <label>Permanent Address District:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Hi Kiran, please edit your question and use the snippet button to add your code - don't add it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap all the labels in a single row.
Then all the inputs in another row below.
And set 25% width for the columns inside:

```
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.w-100prc {
    width: 100%;
}

.w-25prc {
    width: 25%;
}

<div class="d-flex flex-column w-100prc">
    <div class="d-flex w-100prc">
        <div class="w-25prc">
            LABEL 1
        </div>
        <div class="w-25prc">
            LABEL 2
        </div>
        <div class="w-25prc">
            LABEL 3
        </div>
        <div class="w-25prc">
            LABEL 4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex w-100prc">
        <div class="w-25prc">
            INPUT 1
        </div>
        <div class="w-25prc">
            INPUT 2
        </div>
        <div class="w-25prc">
            INPUT 3
        </div>
        <div class="w-25prc">
            INPUT 4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```